# Populating a Table View - How to Return No Cell Under Certain Conditions

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am populating a UITableView using its delegate methods. Under certain conditions I'd like to return no cell. However the following delegate function requires me to define a UITableViewCell as a return type. Returning nil does not work (see switch case in the code example).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    switch (indexPath.section){
        case 0:
                switch (indexPath.row){
                    case 0:
                        if ([eventItemObject eventDescription]){
                            return cell;
                        } else {
                            return nil;
                        }
                        break;
                        ...
                    default:
                    break;
                }
            break;
            ...
        default:
        break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

How to return no cell under certain conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can't do it like this (please correct me when I'm wrong).
You have to return a UITableViewCell instance in the cellForRow method.

Try to edit your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`method. Return only the correct number, according to your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

you have to work with this using the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` or `numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView`

Comment: Well, that makes sense. Oh no, but then I have the problem that the numeration of my switch cases does not fit any more. Noooo...

Comment: actually you still have to use it if you have multiple sections to determine which NSArray to read the data from

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to filter your array to remove any items where [eventItemObject eventDescription] would return false, and then use that filtered array to populate your table. That way, your numberOfRowsInSection and/or numberOfSectionsInTableView will return the correct number.